# Godot: How to vertically align bbcode

Tags: vertical-alignment, godot, bbcode

is there a way to vertically align the text like this using bbcode?

```
[img=16]res://icon.png[/img] Hello World
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Sadly Godot does not have any [BBCode tags](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/gui/bbcode_in_richtextlabel.html) for vertical alignment. As a result there is no straight forward way to vertically center. But there are some things we can do…*

---

**Default: text at the bottom**

As you have seen, you get the text at the bottom of the image by default with this:

```
[img=16]res://icon.png[/img]Hello World
```

---

**Table: text at the top**

We can get the text at the top if we use a table, like this:

```
[table=2][cell][img=16]res://icon.png[/img][/cell][cell]Hello World[/cell][/table]
```

*Then you could use new lines to move it down (or you can combine this with the custom tag below). I'd argue this is more versatile solution.*

---

**Trick to move image vertically**

The documentation suggest this trick: we can create an empty `BitmapFont` resource, and give it some positive `ascent`. Then show the image with that font.

In my case I create a font called `v.tres`, so my BBCode for this is the following:

```
[font=v.tres][img=16]res://icon.png[/img][/font]Hello World
```

The result is moving the image up that many pixels as we said in `ascent`. *And presumably you can figure out how much to move the image up to get the alignment you want (And yes, this would mean different `BitmapFont` resource for different values of `ascent`).*

---

**Custom tag to move text vertically**

Godot allows to define custom BBCode tag, so let use that to move the text vertically.

I will show how to make this work:

```
[img=16]icon.png[/img][valign px=8]Hello World[/valign]
```

First create a `valign.gd` script with this code:

```
tool class_name RichTextVAlign extends RichTextEffect

var bbcode := "valign"

func _process_custom_fx(char_fx:CharFXTransform) -> bool:
    char_fx.offset = Vector2.UP * char_fx.env.get("px", 0.0)
    return true
```

See that we are reading a `px` attribute, with default value of `0.0` with `char_fx.env.get("px", 0.0)`, and we use that value to displace the text by setting `char_fx.offset`.

And then in the `RichTextLabel` add a new `RichTextVAlign` (which is the class we created) to the `custom_effects` property.

*Keep in mind we are moving the baseline of the text (if you are doing this inside the table approach described earlier, you can think of it as moving the top of the text. Yes, use negatives to move it down). We have no way to get the height of the block of text.*

Answer (score 0):

Add a carriage return with /n between image and text.